# Setting fourcc in OpenCV-python & mac does not work

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am using OpenCV-python to acquire camera frame.

The environment I use is as follows

- OpenCV-python : 3.4.2
- OS : macOS Catalina 10.15.6
- cam : Arducam IMX291 B0200

According to the documentation, if I use mjpg on my camera, it is guaranteed up to 25 fps.
So, I tried to set mjpg in fourcc of VideoCapture using the code below, but it did not work.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
print(cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc))

>> False
```

When I ran the same code using the same version of OpenCV-python in ubuntu 18.04, it worked as desired.

How can I set up fourcc on VideoCapture on macOS?

Comment: Did you try `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")` or `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')`?

Comment: @Ahmet Thanks for posting the answer.
I tried both, but the results were the same. It doesn't seem to be a matter of language. Even if I use opencv c++ on macos, the above code does not work.

Comment: Well if I post as an answer, I would get million of downvotes :D, what error do you get? Not opening the camera? no output video?

Comment: @Ahmet 
Even if I fail to change the fourcc, I can get the camera frame. However, it can only receive 5-6 frames per second. When the same code was run on ubuntu, fourcc of videocapture could be changed to mjpg, and 25 frames per second could be received.

Comment: So after 5-6 seconds, the camera stops recording?

Comment: @Ahmet What I mean is 5 fps. I need to set up fourcc for more frames per second.